# nexus S with self built Android system is not working

Tags: custom-roms

I have an unlocked Nexus S. I downloaded the latest Android source code and built it with lunch option "full_crespo-userdebug". I followed the instructions on the official website and boot my Nexus S with the new image. 
Then phone boots up. But I can not enable Wifi or bluetooth in settings (failed after a long hang). A black screen will show when I open the camera. It seems that there are some problems with the device driver! Does anybody have any clue?

Comment: This site is for users of Android, which means that questions about development/programming (including "building your own ROM and finding/debugging its drivers") are off-topic here (see the [FAQ](http://android.stackexchange.com/faq#what-about-other-android-related-questions)). Development questions are on-topic on our sister site [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android). You might also wish to consult [Where can I ask questions that aren't Android Enthusiast questions?](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/q/371/16575) to find a fitting place for your question.

Comment: Sounds like you didn't [get the drivers](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/drivers#crespo)